# Schema structure suggestion for NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql

I have some problem in `Node.js` and `MongoDB` API

- My schema : 
  https://codeshare.io/G6g0xo
- My Code snippet : 
  https://codeshare.io/5OzbW7

As `MongoDB` is `NoSQL` we can't use relational query just like SQL, So I have to grab business from all businesses then find users for that business then have to check user role (according to logic) and then I can find devices info, where I got device token for sending push notification for mobile and web with bifurcation of the `device_type` whether is web or mobile.

So that way I can send a push notification, now the problem arises while I get additional information from a client like we need to store notification in the schema, So after sending push notification I have to store notifications into one schema. while updating my code to store that notification some of the notification stored and some weren't, I need to know what's wrong with my situation (code structure or data structure).

I know I have to manage data structure just like `RDBMS`. if I am wrong with the data structure to enlight me with the proper structure according to `MongoDB` structure and if the structure is not problem guide me with code structure.?

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies within your code

```
let count = 0;
tokens.forEach(function (to) {
    let message = {
        to: to,
        notification: {
            title: varConst.APP_NAME,
            body: notification
        },
        data: payload
    };

    fcmWeb.send(message, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Something has gone wrong!");
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
        }

        count++;
        if (count == tokens.length) {
            callback("Send All");
        }
    });
});
```

In the above code block instead of using forEach you can just give the array of registration ids and fcm will take care of the rest.

```
let message = {
    registration_ids:["eJ8-S5jddyI:APA91bG1jmJBVEtB04","eJ8-S5jddyI:APA91bG1jmJBVEtB04"],
    notification: {
        title: varConst.APP_NAME,
        body: notification
    },
    data: payload
};
```